# distinctUntilChanged filters all MotionEvent values except first

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

distinctUntilChanged filters all MotionEvent values except first
When i log all values from flow, i see bunch of MotionEvent(action=ACTION_MOVE...) and MotionEvent(action=ACTION_UP...) when "cancel" touch

When i add `distinctUntilChanged()` only first MotionEvent logs out

How i can fix this? or What i do wrong?

extension:

```kotlin
fun View.touchEventFlow(): Flow<MotionEvent> {
    return callbackFlow {
        val touchEventListener = OnTouchListener { _, event ->
            trySendBlocking(event)
            return@OnTouchListener false
        }
        this@touchEventFlow.setOnTouchListener(touchEventListener)
        awaitClose {
            Timber.d("awaitClose touchEvent")
            this@touchEventFlow.setOnTouchListener(null)
        }
    }
}
```

fragment emitter:

```kotlin
    private lateinit var rootView: View
    var listener: OnInitialSearchFragmentInteractionListener? = null

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        listener?.callbackTouchEvent(rootView.touchEventFlow())
    }
```

fragment collector:

```kotlin
    override fun callbackTouchEvent(eventFlow: Flow<MotionEvent>) {
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            eventFlow
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .onEach { Timber.d("eventFlow =$it") }
                .collect()
        }
    }
```

Comment: IIRC motion event object you receive in callback is mutable and for efficiency sake you keep receiving the exact same instance with altered values which means distinction will never be true. It is not intended to be captured or compared (which distinctUntilChanged does).